# What does the "System" property for files in MSI setup projects mean?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I've added a file manually to a Visual Studio 2010 MSI Setup Project. The file has a bunch of properties like `ReadOnly`, `Folder`, and `Exlude`. What I don't understand is the property `System`, which has the description:

> Specifies whether to install a selected assembly as a system file

What does that mean? What is a `System file` in this context? I'm installing the file targeted for the Global Assembly Cache Folder. Does it matter whether or not I set `System file` to true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sets the MSDOS file attributes.  I'm pretty sure the only thing this is used for these days is for windows explorer to show the file to the user or not depending on the explorer settings. (hide system files setting)